# how to cast java Object to Object[]?

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting

How to cast java Object to java Object[] or Integer[]
Error(I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;);

```
public class LongestAscendingSumSequence {

    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 20, 3, 25, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34 };
        System.out.println(getSum(arr));
        float[] brr = { 1.3f, 2.3f };
        System.out.println(getSum(brr));
        int[] crr = { 1, 2, 3, 20, 3, 25, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, -2 };
        System.out.println(getSum(crr));

    }

    public static String getSum(Object obj) {
        Object[] objects = (Object[]) obj;

        System.out.println(objects.length);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Getting error for this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at jan25.LongestAscendingSumSequence.getSum(LongestAscendingSumSequence.java:16)
    at jan25.LongestAscendingSumSequence.main(LongestAscendingSumSequence.java:7)
```

Comment: `ìnt[]` is not an `Object[]`, thus the exception. Even covariance does not help in this case. If you were using `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`, it [would be working](https://ideone.com/gsNcZJ).

Comment: This is why the various library functions like `Arrays.sort` have a bunch of overloads for primitive arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to cast primitive types to `Object` which is not allowed.

You need [Wrapper](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wrapper-classes) classes for this approach. E.g.:

```
Integer[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 20, 3, 25, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34 };
System.out.println(getSum(arr));
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gsNcZJ)

Answer (score 0):

Note: This does not support calculating sum results outside the `double` range. You should look into BigDecimal if you need that.

```java
public static <T extends Number>double getSum(T[] tArray) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (T t : tArray) sum = sum + t.doubleValue();
    return sum;
}
```

You need to use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.

Comment: For whatever reason, I can't edit this. I forgot to note you need to use Integer[] instead of int[]

Comment: You do not actually answer the question as of why the `ClassCastException` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you should use Wrapper Types here, for example Integer over the primitive int. The classCastException here occurs because it is trying to cast a primitive int to Object type and neither by widening or unchecked narrowing can one reach from int to Object as int doesn't inherit from Object type.